# Error: Failed to parse Dockerrun JSON file: json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into int

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting the below error in elastic beanstalk logs:

> Elastic Beanstalk :Error: Failed to parse Dockerrun JSON file: json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into int**
> when trying to deploy multi container applications to elastic beanstalk.

Below is my docker file

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "client",
      "image": "imagename1",
      "hostname": "client",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "server",
      "image": "imagename2",
      "hostname": "api",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "worker",
      "image": "imagename3",
      "hostname": "worker",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "imagename4",
      "hostname": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": ["server", "client"],
      "memory": 128
    }
  ]
}
```

What can be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: Is it multi-docker or single-docker EB environment?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue myself. It is as Marcin says. Upon the creation of the environment you need to select Docker and then make sure to specify the multi docker version below that drop down. The Udemy course you are following was using an older UI of AWS which is probably why you missed it the first time around.